# Can i create a pdf file without page break or split using php and fpdf

Tags: fpdf

Using fpdf dynamically i create a document file but problem is in alignment. To show one particular section in one page sometimes it lefts some extra space in footer part. So i want to create a document file so that there will be no page split. When my content if end the file is end. Is it possible?

```
$doch = $pdf->GetPageHeight();
$nowh = $pdf->GetY();
$remh = $doch - $nowh;
if ($remh < 60) {
   $pdf->AddPage();
}
```

Note: It will be alright without page split.

[image: See This]

Comment: What does the question mark on the image mean in the context of your question? Please [edit] your question and show us the data that will create the problem you are describing. Based just on what you posted it would appear as though your calculation for whether or not to start a new page is incorrect.

Comment: i want to create a document without page split. But How...I don't want add new page. It will be like goes.

Comment: Remove `$pdf->AddPage();` in the code you provided in  your question. If it still goes to a new page then the contents of what you are trying to output are too large for the remaining space so they will flow to a new page.

Comment: yes content is too large it will goes 10-15 pages a4 size..but i dont want page break/split feature... can i make it. it will be one page document. when my content is end the page will end.

Comment: You aren't providing enough information about how you are creating your pages. If you have a footer (and/or header) defined to fpdf pages are going to overflow automatically when the content doesn't fit on the remainder of a page. Again, [edit] your question and provide more of the code that you are using to create the PDF including any header and/or footer definitions.

Comment: its simple i used only header....but all i want to create a pdf like notepad no page break/split ....it will be one page ....when my content end the page will be end ....simple ...how can i create it?